# Window Phone and my wifi network issue

Tags: wifi, nokia-lumia-1320

My Nokia Lumia cannot connect to wifi network. Please help me out.

Comment: Please provide more information. What version of Windows Phone (or Windows 10 Mobile) is your phone running? Can your phone see your wifi network? What exactly happens when you try to connect? Do you get any errors? Can your phone connect to other wifi networks? Can other devices connect to your wifi network? Have you tried restarting the phone and the wireless router?

Answer (score 1):

1. Check out [Why can't I get connected?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17286) and try some of the basic
   troubleshooting steps there.
2. Make sure your phone has the latest software updates. On Start , swipe over to the All apps list, then select Settings  > Update &
   security > Phone update > Check for updates. If you don’t have a
   Wi‑Fi connection, you’ll need to make sure you have a cellular data
   connection to check for updates.
3. If you can't connect to a network that you've connected to before, try deleting the network from your phone, and then reconnect
   from scratch. To delete a known network, in Settings , select
   Network & wireless > Wi‑Fi > Manage > press and hold the network
   name > Delete. Deleting the network will delete the associated
   settings on your phone. After that, select the Wi‑Fi network in the
   list of networks, then try to connect again. If the network is
   protected with a password, you’ll need to enter it again.
4. If there aren't any Wi‑Fi networks listed when you're somewhere that you expect one or more to appear, go to Settings  > Network &
   wireless > Wi‑Fi, turn off Wi‑Fi networking, and then turn it back
   on.
5. Try to connect to a different Wi‑Fi network if you can. This can help you narrow down the problem because you can determine if it’s a
   problem with the specific Wi‑Fi network or with Wi‑Fi in general.
6. Insert a SIM card if you don’t have one in your phone. Some Wi‑Fi features that are specific to a country or region might not be
   available because your phone can’t get location info.
7. Turn off Bluetooth while you’re trying to connect to Wi‑Fi. They can operate on the same frequency, so there might be some
   interference. To turn off Bluetooth, go to Settings , then select
   Devices > Bluetooth > turn off Status.
8. If you don’t see the network name at all, the router or access point might not be set to broadcast the network name. In this case,
   you’ll need to manually connect to the hidden network.